# Color has to cover text and point in the list "LI" CSS

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItEU6.png)I have list and how can I do LI with color in CSS? Color has to cover text and point in the list ... like a line in the table.

```
[<b>LIST</b>
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item
    <ul>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>item</span></li>
</ol>][1]
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous .. "do LI with color in CSS"? ... "cover text and point in the list"? -- which point are you talking about

Comment: Thanks a lot ... yes I did mistake in question.

Comment: Did you get your answer ? I don't see any accepted answers

Comment: yes, I have chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `list-style-position:inside;`

You need to add an element or class selector with the color property like this:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
}

li {
  color: #8c200f;
  background-color: #ffc1b7;
  list-style-position:inside;
  padding: 5px;
}

.classSelector {
  color: #1d5cc1;
  background-color: #d3e4ff;
  border: 1px solid #8c8c8c;
}
```

```html
<b>LIST</b>
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item
    <ul>
      <!-- Element selector is modifiying all <li> items //-->
      <li>sub-item</li>
      <li>sub-item</li>
      <!-- Class selector is modifying the line below//-->
      <li class="classSelector">sub-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks. It is almost what I wanted, but I need to cover color and circle also.

Comment: Can you explain yourself a little bit better @Vova ? What do you mean with "cover  olor and circle also" ?

Comment: @Vova I've modified the snippet, now you can see that the list-style-type in the ul element is a circle, is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

This can be one possible solution:

```css
.first {
  color: red;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
.second {
  color: yellow;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<b>LIST</b>
<ol>
  <li class="first">item</li>
  <li class="first">item
    <ul>
      <li class="second"><span>sub-item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="second"><span>sub-item</span>
      </li>
      <li class="second"><span>sub-item</span>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="first"><span>item</span>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have chosen another.

Answer (score 0):

To apply red color to first level list and black color to second level list. You can try:

```css
li {
  color: red;
}

li ul>li {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<b>LIST</b>
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item
    <ul>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>item</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have chosen another.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want this:

```css
li {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  text-decoration: line-through solid red;
}
```

```html
<b>LIST</b>
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item
    <ul>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>
      <li><span>sub-item</span></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span>item</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have chosen another.